# Google play services lib NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-location

I've tried to use **Location API from google-play-services-lib.**

I've set up project according to the developer page

> http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

After running application it crashes with error. Logcat:

> Failed resolving interface 1013
>   'Lcom/google/android/gms/location/LocationListener;
>
> ```
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.fragments.MyFragment
> ```

`MyFragment implements LocationListener and GooglePlayServices` interfaces.

I have spent lot of time by googling but no solution found. Can someone help? Thank you.

LOGCAT:

```
07-22 14:08:15.329: E/AndroidRuntime(13259): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-22 14:08:15.329: E/AndroidRuntime(13259): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
com.example.fragments.MyFragment
07-22 14:08:15.329: E/AndroidRuntime(13259):    at
com.example.fragments.BaseFragment.getPages(BaseFragment.java:80)
07-22 14:08:15.329: E/AndroidRuntime(13259):    at
com.example.fragments.BaseFragment.onCreate(BaseFragment.java:48)
07-22 14:08:15.329: E/AndroidRuntime(13259):    at
android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1477)


 07-22 14:08:15.329: E/AndroidRuntime(13259):   at
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:893)
07-22 14:08:15.329: E/AndroidRuntime(13259):    at
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
07-22 14:08:15.329: E/AndroidRuntime(13259):    at
android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
07-22 14:08:15.329: E/AndroidRuntime(13259):    at
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
07-22 14:08:15.329: E/AndroidRuntime(13259):    at
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:570)

 07-22 14:08:15.329: E/AndroidRuntime(13259):   at
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1164)
07-22 14:08:15.329: E/AndroidRuntime(13259):    at
android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5114)
07-22 14:08:15.329: E/AndroidRuntime(13259):    at
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2153)
07-22 14:08:15.329: E/AndroidRuntime(13259):    at
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-22 14:08:15.329: E/AndroidRuntime(13259):    at
android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-22 14:08:15.329: E/AndroidRuntime(13259):    at
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-22 14:08:15.329: E/AndroidRuntime(13259):    at
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-22 14:08:15.329: E/AndroidRuntime(13259):    at
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-22 14:08:15.329: E/AndroidRuntime(13259):    at
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
07-22 14:08:15.329: E/AndroidRuntime(13259):    at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-22 14:08:15.329: E/AndroidRuntime(13259):    at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-22 14:08:15.329: E/AndroidRuntime(13259):    at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-22 14:08:15.329: E/AndroidRuntime(13259):    at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-22 14:08:15.329: E/AndroidRuntime(13259):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
Method)
```

Comment: check have you added meta data in manifest ?

Comment: I've used google-play-services in my previous project and everithing was fine. I have tried it without any implementation just implement intefraces and it crashes and I don't know why

Comment: then pls do post ur complete logcat?

Comment: I have edited post with logcat

Comment: try to use with Google API(19)

Comment: I've tried it with Google API but still the same problem.

Comment: I'm verry sorry but it's corporate project, I can't put the code on the web.

Comment: well not whole code but where you get error that part

Comment: It happens when Fragment which implements interfaces from lib is instantiated. I've tried to comment all the the lines where I work with objects from library, I have just iterfaces. public class ForecastFragment extends ListFragment implements
  LocationListener,
  GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
  GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener

When I removed also interfaces app works

Comment: In manifest file I've added into application tag <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

Does google play services need extra permissions?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation, and in my case the problem was that I recently updated to a new android bundle (manually, by downloading the new bundle), but for some reason, I kept the old one on my PC, too.  So, I had two different directories "adt-bundle-windows-x86-________" on my PC.  Normally, this didn't pose any problems, but apparently, the Google Utils were updated into the *older* directory, while I was developing my app in the *newer* directory.  This messed up the whole thing.

My solution was to move the older directory "adt-bundle-windows-x86-________" away so that there was only exactly 1 directory "adt-bundle-windows-x86-________" present on the PC.  Then I updated everything to a clean state with the SDK Manager.  From then on, things worked smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done was to update everything to latest versions and switch to latest Android SDK in the project settings. My starting point was https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/193